# to deserialize json string array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

```
{
   "itemlist":{
      "appid":"ST_UWL",
      "transid":"STAT_ID_7001",
      "overalltransstatus":"O",
      "translastmodifieddate":"04.FEB.2016 00:00:00",
      "requestor":{
         "no":"296111",
         "name":"Sowmya Rao",
         "adid":"SO29"
      },
      "workflow":[
         {
            "no":"296",
            "name":"Sowmya Rao",
            "adid":"SO296",
            "level":"",
            "leveltext":"Employee"
         },
         {
            "no":"813",
            "name":"Swaroop",
            "adid":"SSIV",
            "level":"2",
            "leveltext":"Supervisor"
         }
      ],

   }
}
```

I have a Json string in above format. I have to make a console application in which I have to replace certain keywords from the string with new words and other additions. I tried to deserialize but furthur not able to select the keywords from the array. It gives the error

> "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Array' with C#".

Comment: Show us the code you have used, along with your mapping class.

Comment: ' var dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string,object>>(json);
var postalCode = dict["itemlist"]["workflow"]; '

Comment: First cast the `itemlist` to a type of `Dictionary<string,object>`

`var postalCode = ((Dictionary<string,object>)dict["itemlist"])["workflow"];`

Answer (score 0):

Try to deserialize using JsonConvert instead of JavaScriptSerializer. You will need to add the Newtonsoft.Json nuget package and reference it. The following code will deserialize your string into a dynamic object, using which you can access all of the properties of your item:

```
        dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(str);
        var firstWorkflow = json.itemlist.workflow[0]);
```

Comment: It gives me runtime binding erroe exception.

Comment: "'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'itemlist'"

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the workflow, you must cast the itemlist to a type of `Dictionary<string,object` and again index that item for your key which in this case is `workflow`

```
        public void ParseJson()
        {
            string json =
                "{\r\n   \"itemlist\":{\r\n      \"appid\":\"ST_UWL\",\r\n      \"transid\":\"STAT_ID_7001\",\r\n      \"overalltransstatus\":\"O\",\r\n      \"translastmodifieddate\":\"04.FEB.2016 00:00:00\",\r\n      \"requestor\":{\r\n         \"no\":\"296111\",\r\n         \"name\":\"Sowmya Rao\",\r\n         \"adid\":\"SO29\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"workflow\":[\r\n         {\r\n            \"no\":\"296\",\r\n            \"name\":\"Sowmya Rao\",\r\n            \"adid\":\"SO296\",\r\n            \"level\":\"\",\r\n            \"leveltext\":\"Employee\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n            \"no\":\"813\",\r\n            \"name\":\"Swaroop\",\r\n            \"adid\":\"SSIV\",\r\n            \"level\":\"2\",\r\n            \"leveltext\":\"Supervisor\"\r\n         }\r\n      ]\r\n\r\n   }\r\n}";

            Dictionary<string, object> dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
            object postalCode = ((Dictionary<string, object>)dict["itemlist"])["workflow"];
            //Perform operation on postalCode
        }
```

Comment: object displayDetails = ((Dictionary<string, object>)dict["itemlist"])["PA"]["displaydetails"]

Comment: something like above throws the same error" Cannot apply indexing with [] to expression of type object.

Comment: `(Dictionary<string, object>((Dictionary<string, object>)dict["itemlist"])["PA"])["display details"];`mapping to a custom class is certainly more beneficial because you can deserialize to that type instead of casting to a Dictionary each time

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment for some reason, but here's a correction on the last snippet for displaydetails, that was a 6AM edit on my mobile which didn't go down well with autocorrect. `((Dictionary<string, object>((Dictionary<string, object>)dict["itemlist"]))["PA"])["displaydetails"];`

Comment: Thanks a ton @ColinM :)